# Is there a way to contentEditable element scrolling when the cursor reaches the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, contenteditable

I have a one div with contentEditable you can write anything on this div.Right now when a user types anything on this div and reaches bottom than element scroll so a user can continue typing easily.But now I want to scroll elements when a user reaches the middle of the screen.Is it possible?

```css
.content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 500px;
    font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" contenteditable="true">

</div>
```